# Удаление элемента из слайса

Tags: массивы, golang, указатели

Объясните поведение во второй строке. Изначально было два варианта:

- Вывод не изменится во втором случае
- Вывод изменится и последний элемент будет отсутствовать

Но оказался другой вариант. Как объяснить?

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import "fmt"

type Item struct {
    A int
    B string
}

func remove(slice []*Item, s int) []*Item {
    return append(slice[:s], slice[s+1:]...)
}

func main() {
    x := make([]*Item, 0)
    x = append(x, &Item{1, "2"})
    x = append(x, &Item{2, "3"})
    x = append(x, &Item{3, "4"})
    x = append(x, &Item{4, "5"})
    fmt.Println(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3])
    remove(x, 0)
    fmt.Println(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3])
    x = remove(x, 3)
    fmt.Println(x[0], x[1], x[2])
}
```

> &{1 2} &{2 3} &{3 4} &{4 5}
>
> &{2 3} &{3 4} &{4 5} &{4 5}
>
> &{2 3} &{3 4} &{4 5} // тут была бы паника для третьекго элемента
>
> Program exited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Руководство по языку Go, раздел [Appending and copying slices](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)

> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values, append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise, append re-uses the underlying array.

В функции `remove` массив, на который указывает `slice`, достаточно велик, чтобы хранить результат `append`-а. При вызове `remove(x, 0)` в функцию `remove` значение `x` было скопировано. Но скопирован был не сам массив, а его дескриптор - структура, содержащая указатель на массив, дескриптор типа и число элементов.

Поэтому, когда вы вызвали `remove(x,0)`, операции производились на массиве, на который указывает `x`. В нем элементы с позиций 1,2,3 были скопированы на позиции 0,1,2. Элемент на позиции 3 остался доступным, так как в дескрипторе массива `x` написано "в массиве четыре элемента".

После вызова `x = remove(x,3)` в переменную `x` сохранён новый дескриптор массива, в котором написано "в массиве три элемента". В результате последний элемент перестал быть видным.