# Метод append в Golang

Tags: golang

недавно начал изучать Golang и столкнулся с недопониманием работы метода append. Например, есть слайс, из которого нужно убрать третий элемент и результат присвоить второму слайсу. Не понимаю, почему, если я присваиваю результат второму слайсу, то первый слайс тоже меняется и в нем появляется еще одна пятерка.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    firstSlice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    i := 2
    secondSlice := append(firstSlice[:i], firstSlice[i+1:]...)

    fmt.Println(firstSlice)  //[1 2 4 5 5]
    fmt.Println(secondSlice) //[1 2 4 5]


}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/9nC99QfYomb

Comment: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro Slicing does not copy the slice’s data

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1425602/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0 + https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro

Comment: `firstSlice[:i]` — указывает на тот же исходный массив, так что когда вы добавляете в него `4`, `5`, то фактически пишите поверх исходного массива.

Comment: Забавный эффект будет если сделать так: `secondSlice := append(firstSlice[:i], 4, 5, 6, 7)`, то исходный массив не портится. Потому что в нём не хватает места на добавление 4 элементов и append выделяет новую область памяти, копирует два исходных значения и дописывает новые.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Совсем вылетело из головы, что слайс ссылается на массив

Answer (score 0):

Срез в го изменяемая структура, которая передаётся по ссылке. Поэтому, когда вы создаёте второй срез на основе первого -- вы фактически создаёте срез на основе тех же элементов (такая неочевидная оптимизация).

Более того, если в результате append превышена ёмкость среза -- вы получаете *другой* срез. Наполнение такое же, но физически *другой*. Мелочи, про которые надо помнить.